# Custom application page form for content type

Tags: content-type, application-pages, field-controls

Is it possible to copypaste SP field controls from default NewDocSet.aspx to a new custom application page? Or I need to recreate all input controlls manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you recreate the controls manually for better control on your new custom page. You can also copy paste the SP Controls, but should not refer anything that is not available in your page Context.

http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2011/06/sharepoint-custom-addeditdisplay-form.html